# Django Rest Framework: Unable to see view or individual files

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to upload file and then trying to see the files in the list view. For example, I would like my uploaded files to show at `/files/upload/` and I would like to see each individual item at `files/upload/1` or `files/upload/file-name`.

I have created a model and view but I cant seem to find the url to access it. For instance, the pattern Django gives is

```
api/v1/files ^upload/$ [name='lessonpdfmodel-list']
api/v1/files ^upload/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='lessonpdfmodel-detail'
```

The only thing I saved is a file called `pokemon.pdf`

what is that url? is it `localhost:8000/files/upload/pokemon.pdf`?

My Model is:

```
class LessonPDFModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pdf = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to='pdfs/')
    icon = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to='images/')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['upload_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

My View is:

```
class LessonPDFViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LessonPDFModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LessonPDFModelSerializer
```

My serializers is:

```
class LessonPDFModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # file_uploaded = FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = LessonPDFModel
        fields = ('pdf', 'description', 'upload_date')
            
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return LessonPDFModel.object, create(**validated_data)
```

my urls is:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('upload', LessonPDFViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your URL should be `localhost:8000/pdfs/pokemon.pdf`.

because Django saves model data into the media folder.

and don't forget to set media path in settings.py and urls.py